# take picture from Android app and after I want to change color picture with button

Tags: android, sdk, android-ndk

I´ve got an Android app that I developed, but my challenge is that once  I´ve got the picture, I need to be able to change the picture effect, for example, gris to sepia effect.

Comment: You want to change the picture colour *after* taking it?

Comment: please, describe your question more clearly.

Answer (score 1):

Using this method you should be able to acheive your goal.

```
public static void SepiaEffect(Drawable drawable) {


if (drawable == null)

return;



final ColorMatrix matrixA = new ColorMatrix();
  // making image B&W
  matrixA.setSaturation(0);

  final ColorMatrix matrixB = new ColorMatrix();
  // applying scales for RGB color values
  matrixB.setScale(1f, .95f, .82f, 1.0f);
  matrixA.setConcat(matrixB, matrixA);

  final ColorMatrixColorFilter filter = new ColorMatrixColorFilter(matrixA);
  drawable.setColorFilter(filter);
}
```